# Service fabric actor state and list

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

Is it recommended to have a list in Service fabric actor? I am trying to keep User favorites in a User Actor. What is best approach for this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as you treat the list as immutable.

> The state manager retrieval methods return a reference to an object in
>   local memory. Modifying this object in local memory alone does not
>   cause it to be saved durably. When an object is retrieved from the
>   state manager and modified, it must be reinserted into the state
>   manager to be saved durably.

-

> The UserInfo type below demonstrates how to define an immutable type
>   taking advantage of aforementioned recommendations.

```
[DataContract]
// If you don’t seal, you must ensure that any derived classes are also immutable
public sealed class UserInfo {
   private static readonly IEnumerable<ItemId> NoBids = ImmutableList<ItemId>.Empty;

   public UserInfo(String email, IEnumerable<ItemId> itemsBidding = null) {
      Email = email;
      ItemsBidding = (itemsBidding == null) ? NoBids : itemsBidding.ToImmutableList();
   }

   [OnDeserialized]
   private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context) {
      // Convert the deserialized collection to an immutable collection
      ItemsBidding = ItemsBidding.ToImmutableList();
   }

   [DataMember]
   public readonly String Email;

   // Ideally, this would be a readonly field but it can't be because OnDeserialized
   // has to set it. So instead, the getter is public and the setter is private.
   [DataMember]
   public IEnumerable<ItemId> ItemsBidding { get; private set; }

   // Since each UserInfo object is immutable, we add a new ItemId to the ItemsBidding
   // collection by creating a new immutable UserInfo object with the added ItemId.
   public UserInfo AddItemBidding(ItemId itemId) {
      return new UserInfo(Email, ((ImmutableList<ItemId>)ItemsBidding).Add(itemId));
   }
}
```

more info: [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-work-with-reliable-collections) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-work-with-reliable-collections)