# Service Fabric - managing states with StateManager and lists for a reliable actor

Tags: c#, azure, actor, azure-service-fabric

I'm wondering how does StateManager work when dealing with arrays or lists.. I'm having some trouble understanding the concepts behind it like:

1. How does StateManager detect change in a List/Array with CustomClass elements?
2. What happens if multiple changes happen in that List/Array in a single Actor method call? For example, what happens in this use case:

   ```
   List<CustomClass> listEvents = await StateManager.GetOrAddStateAsync("listEvents", new List<CustomClass>());
   listEvents[0] = new CustomClass(...);
   var c = listEvents[1];
   c.SomeField = "Update";
   StateManager.AddOrUpdateStateAsync("listEvents", listEvents, (k, v) => v);
   ```
3. Can StateManager.GetOrAddStateAsync be called multiple times on the same key in a single actor method call?
4. What does StateManager.SaveStateAsync() really do? What happens if I call it and after an error occurs?

For the life of me, I can't manage to make StateManager work in Realiable Actors.. if there are any other pitfalls that I should take into account would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ah jeez, I should stay off SO until after 10am, when I wake up. Deleted my answer because it wasn't relevant.

Comment: Sure thing, no biggie.. thanks anyway. Weird I can't find any answers anywhere.. the State Management section page provided by Microsoft Docs doesn't talk about any of this things... only primitive types and no examples of storing arrays...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46418958/5946937 Same thing applies to Actor State and Service state

Comment: @Alex what do you mean how does it detect changes? It's just a (concurrent) dictionary. Whatever you put in the dictionary is what it saves. AddOrUpdate just means that if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary then it will add it, otherwise it will update the value that is currently in there. How you do that update is up to you. You can just replace whatever is there or have special semantics around updating it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-reliable-collections You should probably read this article @Alex. It sounds like you're not really familiar with how Stateful services work in Service Fabric.